# Repeater not firing proper with Divs on page in asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, repeater, slide

I want to make a slideshow with **divs** in repeater items. there are two **divs** with different classes and cannot show page properly with it. Could you help me please to fix the problem?

**Design cs** is like this:

```
   <div id="wowslider-container1"> 
   <asp:Repeater ID="rpSlideshow" runat="server" >
                    <ItemTemplate> 

            <div class="ws_images">
                <ul>
                    <li id="<%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %>">                        
                        <img src="Yazar/data1/images/<%#Eval("Resmi") %>" alt="<%#Eval("AdSoyad") %>" title="<%#Eval("AdSoyad") %>"
                            id="<%#Eval("SlideID") %>" />

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="ws_bullets">
                <div>
                    <a href="#" title="<%#Eval("SlideID") %>"><span>
                        <img src="Yazar/data1/tooltips/<%#Eval("Resmi") %>" alt="<%#Eval("AdSoyad") %>" /><%#Eval("SlideID") %></span></a>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="ws_shadow">
            </div>

     </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:Repeater>
   </div>
```

**PS**: I tried to combine divisions like below but it did not work proper.

```
        ((HtmlGenericControl)(e.Item.FindControl("myDiv"))).
           Attributes["class"] = "id" + indexi++;
```

Comment: I do not see myDiv in mark up. Question is missing a lot of codes. Please show us [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Tried to change container as below before I wrote this question; <asp:Repeater ID="rpSlideshow" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpSlideshow_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div id="myDiv"> ...

Answer (score 0):

You need `runat="server"` attribute, if you want to access it at code behind.

```
<div id="myDiv" runat="server">...</div>
```

***TIP:*** For that purpose, we normally use ***Panel*** server control which basically renders html ***div*** tag. The advantage is you can use strongly type ***CssClass*** property.

```
<asp:Panel id="MyPanel" runat="server">...</asp:Panel> 

Usage: ((Panel)e.Item.FindControl("MyPanel")).CssClass = "id" + indexi++;
```

*Please note that I rename the control id to MyPanel.*